# Unable to correctly implement a binding between the property value of an object and the property value of a control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to update textedit control through the Client class object databindings with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and i can't get it to work. The object behind (datasource) updates but the textedit still remains blank. If i type the text into the editbox the datasource gets updated. Would you help please? Here's the relevant code i'm using:

```
public class Client : NotifyProperyChangedBase
{

    private string _firstname;
    public string Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return this._firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            this.CheckPropertyChanged<string>("Firstname", ref _firstname, ref value);
        }
    }
}


public Client ClientA = new Client();

Binding fname = new Binding("Text", ClientA, "Firstname", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

ultraTextEditor_firstname.DataBindings.Add(fname);
```

ClientA.Firstname = "testN"; <== editbox remains blank ...

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance, Peter.

Comment: "WinForm INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work" I doubt that very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your base is implemented something along the lines of [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BindBetterINotifyProperty.aspx?display=Print). If I am incorrect in my assumption, you will need to provide the implementation of your NotifyProperyChangedBase class.

You may also want to review the [Binding(String, Object, String, Boolean, DataSourceUpdateMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158045.aspx) constructor documentation, as it discusses the control events the binding attempts to locate.

Looking at that example, you will want to try something like this:

```
System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Client> bindings = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Client>();

Client clientA = bindings.AddNew();
clientA.Firstname = "John";

textEditControl.DataSource = bindings;

// This change presumably will be refelected in control
clientA.Firstname = "Jane";
```

**Update**:
After reviewing the documentation on the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5wdkdt3.aspx) method of the [ControlBindingsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b00cc5k.aspx) class; I believe that the data source of the Binding needs to implement the [IListSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource.aspx) interface in order to properly participate in the binding (all MSDN examples are DataSet or DataTable which implement this interface).

Comment: I think the `CheckPropertyChanged<T>()` raises the event so it's not required to raise again. That is if the OP is using the class from this post http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BindBetterINotifyProperty.aspx?display=Print